# Invoke-command Get-ScheduledTask Clips PSComputerName

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-remoting

```
        invoke-command -computername $server -ScriptBlock { Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "*reboot*"|select (select -ExpandProperty PSComputerName),TaskName,Status }
```

When run the 'TaskPath, TaskName, State, PSComputerName' all respond, but the PSComputerName does not expand, even using the '-ExpandProperty' option I used; I only get the first 12 characters and then three dots.
IDEAS?

Comment: I believe you want to use the `Select-Object` statement outside your `Invoke-Command` scriptblock and, `| Select-Object PSComputerName , TaskName, Status` should suffice

Answer (score -1):

Well, actually, it was a tad more complex than that. See the PSComputerName kept drawing a blank field, so I used variables to solve the problem:

```
#Get-RebootSchedules.ps1
#Search for and respond with the reboot schedules of every server in Production
$servers = gc .\folderthefileisat\serverlist.txt
#$servers="testserver"
foreach($server in $servers){
<#
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { 
$result = (Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "reboot" "\").Date}
$result
}
#>
invoke-command -computername $server -ScriptBlock {
$results = (Get-ScheduledTaskinfo -TaskName "reboot" "\")}
$Server + ($results).TaskName + " will next run at " + ($results).NextRunTime
}
```